# Directory not found when compiling Haskell with Emacs

Tags: shell, haskell

I am trying to learn Haskell, and I have a Haskell file at

```
"c:/Users/Rentian Dong/Documents/rdong6/hw1/Operations.hs".
```

When I try to Haskell-compile it I get the following error output:

```
"ghc -Wall -ferror-spans -fforce-recomp -c c:/Users/Rentian Dong/Documents/rdong6/hw1/Operations.hs

< command line >: does not exist: C:\Users\Rentian


HsCompilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon Sep  4 13:45:24
```

I am using a surface pro 4 with windows 10 pro. Version of Emacs is 25.1.1. I have been searching the internet but was not able to find anything, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Haskell (and little with Emacs) but everything with paths containing unescaped spaces. Your command is parsed as

```
ghc -c "c:/Users/Rentian" "Dong/Documents/rdong6/hw1/Operations.hs"
```

I haven't used DOS/Windows/Powershell for a long time, but in Bash you could fix this by quoting the entire path:

```
ghc -c 'c:/Users/Rentian Dong/Documents/rdong6/hw1/Operations.hs'
```

The old-style Windows filename abbreviation `Rentia~1` should also do the trick.

A better solution would be though to *not pass GHC the entire long path*. Just `cd` there once and then execute everything just with the relative path:

```
cd 'c:/Users/Rentian Dong/Documents/rdong6/hw1'
ghc -c Operations.hs
```

...or in Emacs,

```
M-x cd
"c:/Users/Rentian Dong/Documents/rdong6/hw1"
M-x compile
ghc -fforce-recomp Operations.hs
```

...then, with each new compilation,

```
M-x recompile
```

(or whatever keyboard shortcut you've given this).

Actually, it seldom makes sense to manually invoke GHC *at all*. Why don't you let [Cabal](https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program#Add_a_build_system) (or Stack) do that for you? Then you'd also never need to worry about paths.

Answer (score 1):

You need quotations around `c:/Users/Rentian Dong/Documents/rdong6/hw1/Operations.hs`. The shell is parsing that as two separate arguments (`c:/Users/Rentian` and `Dong/Documents/rdong6/hw1/Operations.hs`) where you only want one. Example:

```
ghc -Wall -ferror-spans -fforce-recomp -c "c:/Users/Rentian Dong/Documents/rdong6/hw1/Operations.hs"
```